# minimizing constraint problem

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Which curve joining the points (0,0) and (1,0) minimizes the integral
$$ J[y]=\int_0^1(y'')^2 dx.  $$
subject to the condition
$$ \int_0^{1} (y')^2dx=1, $$
if $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=\alpha$ and $y(1)=0$.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What have you tried?  Do you know the Euler-Lagrange equation you need to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $y'=u$ then
$$J[y'']=\int(y'')^2 dx\Rightarrow J[u']=\int F(u') dx=\int(u')^2 dx$$
subject to
$$\int_0^{1} (y')^2dx\Rightarrow \int G(u)dx\int (u)^2dx=1$$
The first order condition is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\big(F-\lambda G)-\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial u'}\big(F-\lambda G)\bigg)=0$$
$$-2\lambda u-\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(2u'\bigg)=0$$
$$-2\lambda u-2u''=0$$
where it can be solved
$$u(x)=A\cos(x\sqrt{\lambda})+B\sin(x\sqrt{\lambda})$$
since $y'=u$
$$y(x)=\frac{A}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\sin(x\sqrt{\lambda})-\frac{B}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\cos(x\sqrt{\lambda})+F=C\sin(x\,E)-D\cos(x\,E)+F$$
To satisfy the constraint
$$\int_0^{1} (y')^2dx=\int_0^{1} \bigg(C\,E\,\cos(x\,E)+D\,E\sin(x\,E)\bigg)^2dx=1$$
$$\Rightarrow D-D\cos(E)+C\sin(E)=1$$
and the boundary conditions
$$y(0)=-D+F=0$$
$$y(1)=C\sin(\,E)-D\cos(\,E)+F=0$$
$$y'(0)=C\,E=\alpha$$